# Logistic regression with binomial data in Python

Tags: regression, logistic, python, statsmodels

This is probably trivial but I couldn't figure it out. I want to fit a logistic regression model, where my dependent variable is not a Bernoulli variable, but a binomial count. Namely, for each $X_i$, I have $s_i$, the number of successes, and $n_i$, the number of trials. This is completely equivalent to the Bernoulli case, as if we observed these $n_i$ trials, so in principle I can use, e.g., statsmodels logistic regression after I unravel my data to be Bernoulli observations. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: GLM with family=Binomial estimates the count model where the dependent variable is the number of successes and failures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **statsmodel** package has glm() function that can be used for such problems. See an example below:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

glm_binom = sm.GLM(data.endog, data.exog, family=sm.families.Binomial())
```

More details can be found on the following link. Please note that the binomial family models accept a 2d array with two columns. Each observation is expected to be [success, failure]. In the above example that I took from the link provided below, `data.endog` corresponds to a two dimensional array (Success: NABOVE, Failure: NBELOW).

Relevant documentation: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html

Comment: Vishal.. I think you should put in your answer that you provide a Nx2 matrix for the dependent variable with the counts

Comment: I've added some clarification per your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively using R-style formula

````
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

mod = smf.glm('successes + failures ~ X1 + X2', family=sm.families.Binomial(), data=df).fit()
mod.summary()
```
````

Comment: Is there any reason to import both sm and smf?

Comment: `sm` is needed by `family=sm.families.Binomial()`